# iOS UITabBar - can I modify how many tabs are shown at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm interested **if it is possible to modify the default behavior of UITabBar to display only 4 tabs total, with the 4th tab being ... More.**

By default, tabbar displays up to 5 tabs with the last one being "... more", if tabbar holds more than 5 controllers. My designer expressed the idea that it may be easier for the user to navigate the app if we leave only 3 major controllers in the tab bar, with all "optional" content hidden in the more list.

**Is there a default option or some tweak that I can apply to a UITabBar to change how many tabs it displays at once?**

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Michael Henry suggested you can create the 4th tab as ...More but instead of using a `UITableViewController` why not re-draw the options at the bottom of the `UITabBarController` and show the next set of tabs with the first obviously being Previous...

With this methodology you'd likely have to keep track of what state your TabBar is in so that it properly influences which `UIViewController` is shown upon tapping a tab button on the second page of tabs.

I'm hitting this answer on an iPad or else I'd dump a code example. Sorry.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you suggest linking only 4 view controllers in a storyboard, with the last one being another UITabBarcontroller with more tabs?

Comment: More like re-wiring & re-labeling your existing UITabBarController options with updated options. It's not the most graceful idea but it should work as long as you treat it like a state machine and keep track of where you are.